# Misplacement of UISearchController

Tags: ios, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem with my UISearchController. I can not place it correctly in relation to the tableView.

Table of results does not cover the entire area of the main table:

[image]

```
resultsTableController = ScuoleSearchResultsTableController()
resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true // default is YES
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self    // so we can monitor text changes + others
// Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
// presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
// hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: If you comment out the `definesPresentationContext` line, does that fix it? It looks like this is merely a line that got left in when you copied this code from someone else.

Comment: If that _doesn't_ fix it, you will need to show how you are handling / customizing the presentation of the ScuoleSearchResultsTableController. It is ordinary presentation, and is fullscreen by default, so _you_ must be doing something to it as part of the presentation/animation that messes it up.

Comment: Hi Matt, if I comment that line, doesn't fix. ScuoleSearchResultsTableController is the controller that manages the search, I literally followed the example of Apple.

Comment: from what I understand, it seems a problem of frame of the table that manages the search results. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, obviously. But the question is why. If you followed Apple's example, ScuoleSearchResultsTableController will be a UITableViewController. So its table view is its main view, and will be resized automatically. What we need to know is why that isn't happening. For example, if this table is _inside_ another view, then evidently you forgot to give it constraints to resize it when its superview is resized.

Comment: No, it is just a UITableViewController without any parent view..

Comment: @ClaudioBarbera Have you set the height of the header? Not that I'm 100% sure it's necessary when you set a header in this way... But I'm just checking...

Comment: No, @Lyndsey i've not set height.

Comment: But you've messed with the transition / presentation in some way, right? For example, did you change the transition style so that it is Current Context instead of Full Screen? - And your ScuoleSearchResultsTableController is a storyboard scene, right? You see, I've never done that; I always just create the search controller's table view controller in code.

Comment: I thought I messed up something, but I created a new UITableViewController Storyboard. ScuoleSearchResultsTableController is not a storyboard scene, it's created in code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, I solved simply by flagging an UINavigationController setting:

```
UINavigationBar.translucent = true
```

Thanks for all replies